# unable to find DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntryByTitle() in liferay 6.1

Tags: liferay-6

Is there any direct api to fetch a file entry by title with given folder id.
I have tried DynamicQueryFactoryUtil, apart from this is there anything to fetch DLFileEntries by title.

I believe DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntryByTitle() is not there anymore in Liferay 6.1

Comment: How exactly are you trying to 'find' this method? have you tried checking the other methods of this Class ?

Comment: I am trying to find DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntryByTitle() api or anything equivalent to it. But not thru looping in a folder and then match of the file title.

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay 6.1.0, I can see there is
 `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntryByName(groupId, folderId, name)`, as I get from lib/ext/portal-service.jar

You can also see the official documentation [here](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.html)

I think you start by making sure you have the correct libraries imported

EDIT:
I guess that the parent folder and groupID are needed as more than 2 DLFileEntries can have the same title/name.  If you need exactly 1 result, and giving only 1 attribute, you can use getDLFileEntry(long fileEntryId). If this doesn't help either, you should tell us some more on what you want to do , and what information you have available (except the title of course)

Comment: Yes there is     DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntryByName(..) but not     DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntryByTitle().

Comment: Obviously, the method name that ends with 'ByName' instead of 'ByTitle' is not the issue here. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Liferay has a strange compatibility policy.

Seems like they renamed the getFileEntry to getFileEntryByName and getFileEntryByTitle to [getFileEntry](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.html#getFileEntry(long,%20long,%20java.lang.String)%20getFileEntry). The old and new getFileEntry both share the same singature, but the parameter name is different. :-(